# Changing WooCommerce availability text and include the original HTML

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

**This is what I have right now:**

[image]

The text is not wrapped in the standard WooCommerce HTML.

**This is what I wan't:**

[image: The text output is sourrounded with the HTML WooCommerce]

The text here is correctly wrapped in the standard WooCommerce HTML.

**This is what I've done**

I have added this to functions.php. I'm using Advanced Custom Fields, so I'm storing the contents (plain text) from that field in the $availability variable.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
    // Change Out of Stock Text
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = the_field("text_stock", "option");
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

The text is correctly displayed on the product page, but the HTML normally wrapping the stock information (found in *WooCommerce/templates/single-product/stock.php*) is not being output.

I have tried this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
    // Change Out of Stock Text
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = '<p class="stock ' . esc_attr( $availability['class'] ) . '">' . the_field("text_stock", "option") . '</p>';
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

But that leaves me with this weird output:

[image]

**My questions**

- How can I still output the same HTML?
- How can I output my own HTML if the above is not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `get_field("text_stock", "option")` instead of `the_field("text_stock", "option")`?

Comment: No. And why didn't I... because that worked. **Facepalm**. However it still outputs one additional paragraph without content like in the screenshot above.

Comment: What field type is text_stock? Some field types auto insert <p> tags.

Comment: It's the normal "text" type which outputs a string without any tags or HTML. Just plain text.